# Perl LWP::Simple - A file or directory in the path name does not exist

Tags: perl, aix

I have two AIX hosts, both with same version of Perl installed (5.10.1), both with LWP::Simple module installed.  I run a few Perl one-liners to download files from IBM's RAM.

They use LWP::Simple to first verify the module exists, then get the header for a resource (a file) at some URL to obtain file size, then finally download the file.  It works fine on host #1, but on host #2 I get a couple different errors.

```
perl -e 'eval { require LWP::Simple; } or die 0;'
```

This one runs without issue on both.  I've tested it dies as expected on a machine without LWP::Simple module installed.

```
perl -e 'use LWP::Simple; my @info = head("<URL here>"); die("-1 \$!") unless @info; print "$info[1]\n";'
```

On the problem host, I get "A file or directory in the path name does not exist" here, which I find weird given this is (I think?) a Unix error, but I can't reproduce this on the working host (#1) even by giving a garbage URL for this command.

```
perl -e 'use LWP::Simple; my $localfile = "<target file name here>"; my $url = "<URL here>"; my $status = getstore($url, $localfile); die "-1 \$!" unless is_success($status);'
```

Here I get a 501 error when I run on the problem host.

I reformatted these statements for clarity; it's actually invoked from a C# application via SSH.NET.  Please pardon typos; the upshot is it works absolutely fine on AIX host #1 and not at all on AIX host #2.

Anyone have ideas how to further troubleshoot?

Comment: Hmm...  Try running your Perl command in "truss" on AIX.  Look for failed system calls with ENOENT errors.  Is there anything different from one host to the other?